# how to to use html control radio button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have 2 radio buttons and I want to set a specific condition like,

if `value=1` then save a file on abc location and if `value=2` then save the file xyz location

```
<tr>
    <td class="case_heading" height="20" width="150" align="right">Mode :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="case_txt" height="20" width="250" align="left">
    <input type="radio" name="rbMode" checked value="1" onclick="javascript:GetModeValue(this.value);" />Assignment
    <input type="radio" name="rbMode" value="2" onclick="javascript:GetModeValue(this.value);" />De-Assignment
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That's it ? please share what you have tried in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `Request.Form["radion_button_name"]`

e.g

```
string strPlace='';

if (Request.Form["rbMode"] != null)
 {
     strPlace = Request.Form["rbMode"].ToString();
 }
//=strPlace will return Null if No radio button is selected.
```

and use your code base on the value on selected radio button .

```
if(strPlace=='1')
{
//save image in location 1
}
else if(strPlace=='2')
{
//save image in location 2
}
else
{
//error you have to select the location type using radio button.
}
```